# How can I display Product Images to Logged In Users only, with Logged Out Users seeing an alternative image?

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, plugins, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I would like to modify my WordPress/WooCommerce website, so that my Product Images have the following conditions:

**Logged in site visitors:**

I would like logged in visitors, to be able to see all of the WooCommerce Product Images.

**Logged out site visitors:**

I would like logged out visitors, to see an alternative image.  Therefore, hide the Product Image.  This alternative image, will be the same for every Product.

Comment: Are you looking to replace the Main Product Image, on the Product Page, with one image for those who are not logged in and then the actual Product Image to those who are logged in?

Comment: exactly , you can see it in http://vaporcenter.be/ it must be like it

Comment: How did you get on?  Did my answer help you out at all?

Comment: @Craig Craig i just got 1 more question . Now the people who aren"t logged in can still see the product. But if they look for the specific product they see the alternative image. So my question is , can you disable all pictures from images before logged in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are going to need to create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), for your WordPress/WooCommerce website.

Once created, simply insert the following code, into the `functions.php` file, within your Child Theme:

```
<?php
// Remove Default WooCommerce Product Images/Placeholders.
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

// Create conditional logic function.
function logged_in_images(){
    // If site visitor is Logged in, display Default WooCommerce Product Images/Placeholder.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo woocommerce_show_product_images(); 
    } 
    // If site visitor is not logged in, display the following Image instead. 
    else {
        echo '<img src=http://vaporcenter.be/theme/Wholesale/img/placeholders/default.jpg?1504084579>';
    };
}

// We are inserting ('Hooking' into) the above function into where the Default WooCommerce Product Image/Placeholder was, before we removed it.  
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'logged_in_images', 20 );
?>
```

Be sure to replace http://vaporcenter.be/theme/Wholesale/img/placeholders/default.jpg?1504084579 with your desired image.

Don't forget, you can remove the comments (// ...) from the code.  They are there, to just help explain what is happening.

I have tested the above code and it does work.

Best of luck!

**If you receive an error**

1. Step One:  Using an FTP client, such as Filezilla, go into your Root Folder (Where you installed WordPress).
2. Look for a file entitled `wp-config.php` and drag this to your computer.
3. Open the file, using Notepad/Notepad++ and look for the line `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and change 'false' to 'true'.
4. Drag the `wp-config.php` file back from where you got it from.
5. Refresh the page you are having an issue.  You should then see an error message, which will be helpful in addressing how to resolve any issues.
6. Once you have resolved your issue, and your website is back in working order, head back into your `wp-config.php` and change 'true' back to 'false'.

Comment: Craig i just got 1 more question . Now the people who aren"t logged in can still see the product. But if they look for the specific product they see the alternative image. So my question is , can you disable all pictures from images before logged in ?