# Best practices for IP protection on photography site

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, security

Before all the un-helpful comments come out of the woodwork (i.e. "if you want to protect it, don't upload it") - I get it. The only way to protect it is to not put it out there. Not an option, not helpful. Home security isn't about never allowing someone to break into your home. If they want in, they can cut a hole in the wall if your windows and door are too secure. The idea is to make it harder so the average burglar will move on. That's what I'm looking for here. Make it a pain so the average would-be thief will move on. With that out there here is my situation:

I'm putting the finishing touches on a portfolio site for a photographer. The site is a headless React WP site. I've seen so many "suggestions" for how to protect their copyrighted materials that my head is spinning. "Disable right click." "DON'T disable right click." "Upload only smaller, compressed images." Trust me, I know that a Google search will give tons of answers. Problem is, too many of them are conflicting or generic. I figured I would go to a group of people who are generally more technically savvy, and have probably had to face similar situations.

Here is what I have done so far:

- employed plugins that automatically compress and limit size on uploaded images. This allows the client to upload what they want, and keeps them safe.
- employed plugin that automatically puts copyright info and a QR code onto the image that directs the scanner back to the main page of the site. As the point of the site is to show off the beautiful images, we decided to put them only in the corner, even though covering more of the image would be more effective.
- decided NOT to bother with blocking right click as it's a nuisance at best and is easy to circumvent by users with limited technical knowledge (is this the right call?)

Any other ideas I should entertain?

Comment: *"decided NOT to bother with blocking right click"* - Good call on that one.  It is easily disabled and does nothing to protect data.  While I don't have any specifics, overall it's always good to start with the assumption that anybody who wants to save the images shown on the page can and will, and nothing can stop that.  From there you get to the suggestions like limiting the size (and therefore the usefulness) and, of course, watermarking the images to *drastically* reduce their usefulness.  (Watermarking the *whole* image, not just an easily cropped border.)

Comment: This might be better suited to one of the other stackexchange sites?  This is not really a specific programming question. (maybe https://security.stackexchange.com/, but I am not super familiar with their rules)

Comment: I wish we could watermark the whole image, but that's a non-starter. The artist wants the artwork un-obstructed, so we settled on putting it in the corners, and hoping that would be enough for most. They understand that involves more risk, but feel that is outweighed by their work not being obscured.

Comment: @Nexevis - thank you. I am new to the stack sites, I didn't realize there was a difference. Being a programmer, I am familiar with this one, so it is where I came. I will take the question over there.

Comment: You might also ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.  You might consider showing low-rez images to the public, and restrict access to high-rez images to people who have logged in.  This, maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534675/how-can-i-display-product-images-to-logged-in-users-only-with-logged-out-users